# How to call php file when we receive a mail

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have special e-mail accounts on my web server (@mydomain.com). I want to run a php script automatically when one of these accounts get a new e-mail. For example: when info@mydomain.com address receives a mail, I want to run "receivedMail.php" file and read this new e-mail. I don't know where I will start or how can I do this.

Comment: How about starting with a simple search https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+read+email

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to pipe email received for a specific email address to a PHP script.

If your webhost has cPanel, this makes it very easy to setup. See:

http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_pipe_an_email_to_a_php_script/

Alternatively, if you don't have cPanel but have Exim mailserver, this will guide you on how to do this:
http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a cron job calling your php file every 1 minute for exemple.
The script have to the derver and read the email.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with web servers directly, Since web servers do not receive emails. So no `.htaccess` style files come into play. The email is received by a mail server, so that is where you have to get active. Two strategies are possible:

1. you use the possibilities to trigger an action as offered by your
   mail server (typically the smtp server you operate). That obviously
   depends on which mail server you operate, different software offers
   different features.
2. you poll those email accounts on a regular base, using a standard protocol like POP3 or IMAP4. You can do this using any suitable client. When a new message is found whilst polling the account, then you trigger the action you wish.

Option 2. is probably easier to start with. So give it a try: create a php file which polls your email server. You can use the `imap` php extion for this, it supports all important email protocols. The extensions allows to easily detect and retrieve new messages. For each such message you can implement whatever action you wish. All that is left is to run this script on a regular base, say every 3 minutes, which is typically done using a `cron` system. There are many examples for this out there on google...

Have fun!